# Dell XPS 15 - Ticking sound of subwoofer

Tags: drivers, sound

So...

Here is the thing: I keep hearing a ticking sound coming from the sub-woofer of my Dell XPS 15.  It happens randomly, or at least I can't put it in context, but once it starts it doesn't stop.

It doesn't matter if the sound of the system is in silence, completely low or high. The sounds is there and I am completely lost in both why is it happening, and how I can solve it.

It would be great if anyone has had experience with this kind of problem, or at least if you guys could point me to how I can deal with this.  I have tried using **alsamixer**, but no luck.

I have found this thread: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3517/t/19355283.aspx -- But I fail to see how to do this fix under Ubuntu...

Comment: I don't face it. I have same model. Possibly a hardware issue.

Comment: I didn't use to face it. It works fine in Windows, that's why I am trying to find a fix for Ubuntu :/

Comment: How do you know it's subwoofer, not the HDD chugging away?